# Calling Stored Procedure in Access VBA only with the correct order of parameters, why?

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010, ado

i have a little Problem with executing a stored procedure from Access. I am using the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" together with MS SQL Server 2008.

For now I am calling the stored procedures like this:

```
Set cmd = init_adodbcommand("sp_002_test_tabellenparameter")

cmd.Parameters("@str_test") = "Test"    
cmd.Parameters("@str_test2") = "Test"

cmd.Execute
```

I am ok with that, but there are issues if I am using a nvarchar(max) variable in the stored procedure so I am using this code, which works fine too:

```
    Set cmd = init_adodbcommand("sp_002_test_tabellenparameter")

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@str_test", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, "Test")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@str_test2", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, "Test")

cmd.Execute
```

It works too, BUT only if the parameters are in the correct order, like they are added in the stored procedure on the Server. 
This behaviour doesn't happen for the first option I mentioned at the beginning! With this option I can address the parameter directly.

The Code of the sp on the server starts like that:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_002_test_tabellenparameter]
   -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
   @str_test nvarchar(max) = NULL,
   @str_test2 nvarchar(max) = NULL
```

I have a lot of stored procedures with more than 30 parameters and some of These parameters aren't needed sometimes and I don't won't to "give a shit" about the correct order... :D

It looks like that it doesn't matter which name for the parameter I am using in Access.

Where is my fault?

Thank you! :)

attachment code to initialize:

```
Dim cmd_temp As ADODB.Command
Dim adoconn_connection_tmp As ADODB.Connection

Set adoconn_connection_tmp = New ADODB.Connection

    Set adoconn_connection_tmp = ADOConnObj

    Set cmd_temp = New ADODB.Command

    cmd_temp.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd_temp.CommandText = str_prozedurname
    cmd_temp.ActiveConnection = adoconn_connection_tmp

    Set init_adodbcommand = cmd_temp

End Function
```

Comment: If you add line `cmd_temp.NamedParameters = True` to command object initializer, will that help?

Comment: You did it. THANK YOU :D

Comment: ADO params as far as I know do follow order. The names you give are simply local collection names and do not have to correspond to stored proc named params unless as @Arvo suggests you explicitly align the to sets of names. Also, do note both stored proc [params are optional](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx) (since you set default values). So you can append one, both, or no params and procedure should still run.

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add line

```
cmd_temp.NamedParameters = True
```

to command object initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ADOX Catalog object to inspect the named parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676682(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It doesn't find the stored procedure. I am confused -.-